# Play ストアで「アプリ内購入あり」の表記が反映されるタイミングは？

Tags: android, google-play

最近Androidのアプリ内購入（定期購読）について勉強をしている者です。

早速の質問なんですが、Play Storeにある「アプリ内購入あり」表記はどのタイミングでつくのでしょうか。

いろいろ調べてみたのですが、明確な答えが見当たらず。
請求権限を付与したAPKをアップロードして、定期購読の製品をアクティブ化したタイミングで表記が付くようになるのかなと思っております。
または、アルファ版でもアップロードしたら付くのでしょうか。

ご助力のほど、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

私の環境ではアルファ版でもこれは表記され比較的即時に対応されているように感じられました。
プレイストアの表記はGoogleによりコントロールされています。ですので明確な回答はできません。
こちらに回答がどうしても必要で理由が明示できる場合は、Googleにメールで直接お尋ねいただくのがよいと思います。
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=ja

**問い合わせの結果のコメントをいただいたので付記します**

表記に関して、公開したアプリのマニフェストに次の一行があるかどうかで表示しているようです(実際に有効化されているかどうかには関係しない)。

**<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />**

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Googleに問い合わせたところ、どうやら定期購読の製品を作成し、ステータスを有効にすると表記が表示されるようです。これは定期購読が実際に購入可能な状態になるためだそうです。

Comment: こちらのコメントについてなんですが、誤りだったようです。

何度購入処理を行なってもエラーが返ってしまうので、前回の問い合わせに関して含めて再度問い合わせたところ有効化かどうかは表記に関して連動はしておらず、公開したアプリのマニフェストに次の一行があるかどうかで表示しているようです。

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

誠に申し訳ありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。本文に追加させていただきました。Google Playは結構な範囲人手で行っており、今後も、何か不審な動作がある場合は遠慮なくお問い合わせいただいた方がよいと思います。